# Is there a way to stop a csv from renaming the sheet

Tags: excel, vba, csv

The goal of the script is to delete every blank or empty row after the last populated row.  The point of deleting every blank row is bc I import the sheet into a 3rd party software.  If I don't delete the empty rows I get a bunch of blank rows in the 3rd party software.

What I want to happen is to run the macro inside the sheet, import it into the software, and only see the populated rows.

The below script does that until I get to the save portion.  In the script, there is a define the worksheet section where I'm supposed to define the name of the sheet that is being edited.  The script runs and deletes everything that it should but when I get to the end to save it it changes the name of the sheet from Sheet1 to the name of the actual file.

Ideally the sheet name would stay Sheet1 so that I don't have to tinker with the define the worksheet section.

First question would be, am I missing something simple?  I've tried to add code that dynamically changes the name of Sheet in the code to the actual file name.
Second question, is there a better way to do all of this that I'm not seeing?

```
Sub DeleteEmptyRowsAfterLastPopulatedRow()
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim activeSheetName As String
activeSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name

' Define the worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(activeSheetName)

' Find the last populated row
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Loop through rows after the last populated row and delete empty rows
For i = lastRow + 1 To ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Rows(i)) = 0 Then
        ws.Rows(i).Delete
        i = i - 1 ' Adjust the counter since a row has been deleted
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Did you missed part of the code in OP? There isn't any code to change sheet name.

Comment: CSV files are just plain text files which Excel is able to view as a worksheet.  CSV files *always* display with a worksheet of the same name as the source file.  There's no way to change that: CSV files do not store any information other than the actual data.

Comment: Right.  Do you know of a way to write code that says, "change the define worksheet part to mirror whatever the file name is changed to."

Comment: CSV files have only 1 sheet so if you open them in Excel you can define a worksheet reference as `Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)`. Is that what you want  ?

Answer (score 0):

This code does what the OP requires, for me at least.

The option for legacy text import needs to be switched on to avoid the table formatting and keep the Sheet1 name. Lots of help from the Macro Recorder here.

```
Sub Macro3()
' the legacy text import option is required for this to work
' https://superuser.com/questions/1574847/how-to-import-external-csv-text-file-without-table-formatting
    Dim lastRow As LongLong
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;C:\Users\david\Desktop\Export_Aug Nov 2023.csv", Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
        .Name = "Export_Aug Nov 2023"
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = 850
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim activeSheetName As String
    activeSheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    ' Define the worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(activeSheetName)
    ' Find the last populated row
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("A" & lastRow + 1).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

There is a problem with the connection that this query uses. Each time the code runs a new connection is created. The code to tidy up and delete the connection is as follows -

ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Export_Aug Nov 2023").Delete

If the above code is run twice a `Subscript out of range` error occurs meaning that the connection has been deleted. However, the UI still shows the connection and it can not be deleted via the UI.

The UI does not show the connection if the Workbook is closed and reopened.

Comment: I think we're on the right track with the above code, but I do get an error.... Excel cannot find the text file to refresh this external data range......When I debug the following is highlighted......Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Comment: I can do what I want manually.  Meaning I can open the sheet, highlight the rows, delete the rows, save as a csv, and bring the sheet in without blanks.  But when i try to run any script that deletes the blank rows it imports with every blank row.

Comment: @JoshuaSmith I can not reproduce the blank rows problem as I do not have your 3rd party software. I would suggest that the problem is that the 3rd party software is seeing blank rows where there are none. As a test manually create a CSV file with a small number of rows and import that. If there are blank rows imported it is an error in the 3rd party software.